# isPlatformBrowser and google crawler

Tags: angular, seo

I am using angular universal. I make calls to back-end rest services only if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) is true i.e. only from the browser to avoid same rest services called twice.

Does google crawler see the page  as browser?  I would like back-end rest calls executed when google crawler fetches the page so that the page can get indexed correctly but otherwise I would not want rest services called twice

Comment: If NodeJS on your live server doesn't allow you to send ajax calls, you'll have no other option than to perform these calls from your mvc backend, and pass them on through `SupplyData`. As for your question, I've had mixed results using `isPlatformBrowser`. On the other hand `isPlatformServer` always gives the correct result, you just have to invert it

Comment: Also Google Webmaster tools shows you how they fetched/indexed the page. You can enter any url at any time to test it